# Add default month/day to known year in new date field?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, date

I have a text field featuring a 4 digit year. How would I assign a default month and day to the year in a new date field?

ex. 2010 needs to be converted to 1/1/2010

I attempted this in the field calculator:

```
def dt(year):
    dt_str = year
    dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y')
    return dt_obj
```

install date =

```
dt(!year!)
```

Comment: What was the result of this calculation? Any errors?

Comment: Just kept running and never finished, so not sure.

Comment: This might be due to overloading the method `date` in `datetime` with your new function `date`. Try changing the name of your function to be something else.

Comment: Changed it to no avail. I did receive an error this time though.  ERROR 000539: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in dt
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not int

Comment: That error means your `year` variable is an integer. Just add a line converting it -- `dt_str = str(year)`

Comment: Tried it, similar error. Could it be because the field I'm trying to run this in is in a date data type?

Comment: What is the data type of your source field (`year`)? It looks like it's integer based on the error.  Also please include the text of the new error.

Comment: I was able to test this in ArcGIS Pro 2.x. The only change I made (converting from a string) was a line before the function definition to `import datetime`, and used a different function name. (If I didn't import datetime first, received a large series of errors.) This worked directly in a date-formatted field.

Comment: Added codeblock using date directly (instead of needing an integer column) in your previous question. Please test and confirm whether you are still getting an error.

Comment: do you `import datetime`?

Answer (score 1):

Change the function name to ensure it's not overloading `date` from `datetime`, or overloading a common short version of the `datetime` module (`dt`). Make sure you are importing datetime within the codeblock.

```
import datetime
def extractdate(year):
    #may need to change to str(year) if your input column is numeric
    #year = str(year)
    dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(year, '%Y')
    return dt_obj
```

By default it will use January 1st, but if you want to control the month or date you can add more to the string and convert via strptime.

e.g. 
 `dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(year+'03', '%Y%m')`
would give you all March 1st dates.